# VBS runs VBA Macros in .xlsm workbook fine on one server but not another

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, server-configuration

### Issue:

---

I have a VBScript that opens a .xlsm workbook and executes a few macros.
The code in the VBScript & VBA macros have all been tested and works perfectly, but only on 1 server, the "Production" server.

When attempting to run the VBS on a second server, the "Test" server, the VBS successfully opens the workbook and successfully executes a preliminary macro to gather process information, but then it hits a very cryptic error when attempting to execute the second macro titled "Auto_Run", after that the VBS closes the workbook and executes the rest of its code perfectly.

**Why would this work fine on one server but not the other? Where do I start to troubleshoot this?**

If you think you can help but need me to provide something more, by all means please say so and I will provide it.

---

### Details:

---

The preliminary macro that works is actually 'GetCurrentProcessID' from kernel32. Added to the macro via this line of code:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

The cryptic error returned from the VBScript when attempting to execute the 2nd Macro: "Auto_Run" on the "Test" server is:

```
Err.Source = ""
Err.Code = -2147417851
Err.Description = "<Error> | -2147417851: </Error>"
```

The Sub for the second Macro 'Auto_Run':

```
Sub Auto_Run()
    On Error GoTo e
    QLog "'Auto_Run' Starting..."
    modMain.bAuto = True

    Main bAuto

QLog "'Auto_Run' Completed."
x:
    Exit Sub
e:
    QLog "'Auto_Run' " & Get_Err
    Resume x
End Sub
```

QLog is a sub that writes the contents of the string parameter passed to it to 3 places, 1 the status bar, 2 a progress indication form (that is only displayed optionally when executed manually) & 3, most importantly, to a database log table.

The second executable line of "Auto_Run" doesn't even execute:

```
        QLog "'Auto_Run' Starting..."
```

should log to the database log table, but of course it is empty.

---

### Event Viewer:

---

I checked the Application Log in Event Viewer and found 3 related events.

1 'Application Error' type event:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.7177.5000, time stamp: 0x582c88af
Faulting module name: VBE7.DLL, version: 7.0.16.40, time stamp: 0x57fbbbf8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000278d
Faulting process id: 0x1c0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2710609568608
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL
Report Id: 488b9548-dcf9-11e6-bf1b-3a017bdb52e6
```

1 'Windows Reporting Error' information type event:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: EXCEL.EXE
P2: 14.0.7177.5000
P3: 582c88af
P4: VBE7.DLL
P5: 7.0.16.40
P6: 57fbbbf8
P7: c0000005
P8: 000000000000278d
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\2\CVRA045.tmp.cvr
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA9F5.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERAB0F.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERAB2F.tmp.hdmp
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERADA0.tmp.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_EXCEL.EXE_33353b1e5e166abad4dbe725c82a3feea72c43_cab_be21aeb6

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c39d1908-dcfb-11e6-bf1b-3a017bdb52e6
Report Status: 4
```

and lastly 1 more 'Windows Error Reporting' information type:

```
Fault bucket 422681129, type 28
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: EXCEL.EXE
P2: 14.0.7177.5000
P3: 582c88af
P4: VBE7.DLL
P5: 7.0.16.40
P6: 57fbbbf8
P7: c0000005
P8: 000000000000278d
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\2\CVRA045.tmp.cvr
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA9F5.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERAB0F.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERAB2F.tmp.hdmp
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\WERADA0.tmp.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_EXCEL.EXE_33353b1e5e166abad4dbe725c82a3feea72c43_b759b319

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c39d1908-dcfb-11e6-bf1b-3a017bdb52e6
Report Status: 0
```

### What I have tried

---

I tried setting the Excel Application's Visible property to True
& adjusting the "Auto_Run" Sub to something much simpler to see if it would execute & it did not.

VBS:

```
oXL.Visible = True
oXL.Application.Run "'" & sName & "'!" & sMacro
```

VBA

```
Sub Auto_Run()
    'Test
    MsgBox "Help Me Please"
End Sub
```

---

**Replies to Comments**

---

Comintern   -

```
These servers are on the same network & the program is being executed by the same AD User.
What other permissions would I have to adjust?
```

ClintB  -

```
Running under the same AD user on the same network. Also, Excel is successfully opening & executing the first macro, just not the 2nd one.

-- Full Automation Works
Prod Server OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 - 64 bit
Prod Server XL: 14.07177.5000 (32-bit)

-- Doesn't work
Test Server OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 - 64 bit
Test Server XL: 14.07177.5000 (64-bit)
```

Nick.McDermaid  -

```
Manual Execution on either server works as expected.
```

---

P.S.
I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find anything on this. I'm probably phrasing it poorly but I figured it was worth a shot to ask about it.

Comment: `0xc0000005` is basically "access denied". I'd check permissions on the problem machine.

Comment: Are all the machines the same operating system? 
32bit or 64bit?
What user are you running this under? 
By Default the user 'system' cannot open excel files and run them.

Comment: What happens when you open the excel and run the macros manually?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. To answer your questions - I've appended the question at the end.

Comment: Maybe macros are disabled on production server?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it all comes down to the architecture & the drivers.

**I managed to execute the 2nd macro successfully with VBS after reinstalling office professional 2010 as 32-bit instead of 64 bit.**

On a separate note, switching from 64bit to 32bit fixed that problem but created a few others for me. This broke processes I had set up based on the 64-bit AccessDatabaseEngine driver I had installed to query excel files into SQL Server tables using 'OpenRowSet' & 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', so I ended up reinstalling 64-bit since that functionality was more important to me. I could've re-installed SQL Server as 32-bit which also would've worked, & probably would've been the better long term solution since I would have both features functioning properly, but that seemed to be more of a hassle at the moment. Also, 64-bit SQL Server handles memory much better then 32-bit which is another reason why I opted this route.

For anyone experiencing the second part of this issue, I found a reference that put this into perspective quite nicely: 
https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm

also this one:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2010/06/04/accessing-excel-files-on-a-x64-machine/